# Saxon and XML Schema 1.1 custom validation messages

Tags: xml, xsd, saxon

I've been thinking about using Saxon 9.6 as XSD 1.1 validator with XSD Assertions. Is it possible to define my own error messages (not the default ones) using Saxon validator?

Comment: See [net.sf.saxon.s9api.SchemaManager.getErrorListener()](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/SchemaManager.html#getErrorListener())  and [setErrorListener()](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/SchemaManager.html#setErrorListener(javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener))

Answer (score 1):

Several mechanisms come to mind.

First, you can define your own messages associated with assertions and indeed other facets:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing/extensions11/saxon.message

Second, you can send all validation messages to an XML report file, which you can then transform. Use `-report:filename` on the Validate command line, or `SchemaValidator.setValidityReporting()` in the s9api API. The format of the report file is defined by a schema which is available in the `saxon-resources.zip` download file.

You could use an `ErrorListener` as suggested by @kjhughes - the error information in the `ValidationException` object passed to the ErrorListener is in quite a structured form - but (a) I think the XML report is easier to manipulate, and (b) we have found that in validation runs reporting a few hundred errors, the cost of creating the exception objects needed by the `ErrorListener` interface can be quite a significant part of the overall run time. Java Exceptions weren't really designed for this purpose.

Comment: The saxon:message is really great, although it is usable for facets only. Is it possible to somehow define custom messages for structural validation too (cplx types, etc.)? Thanks

Comment: No, sorry. I've thought about it but haven't found a way. The problem is that there's no simple correspondence between parts of the complex type definition and error messages. Saxon goes to some effort to try to work out what is really wrong when your input is invalid against a complex type, leading to messages along the lines "The X element is not valid here but it would be valid if it were in namespace N".

Comment: Yes, I thought so. There is no simple way how to draw a connection between the cplx type definition and related error messages. Thanks anyway!